# DOMElement, how to (do a simple) check if an attribute exists?

Tags: php, dom

In a code,

```
 $c = $node->getAttribute('class');
 if (exist $c) {do somthing};
```

how to check?

The [return value of both, none and empty, are the same(!)](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php):

> The value of the attribute, or an empty string if no attribute with the given name is found.

PS: WHY (??) it not returns NULL for "not has attribute"?

Comment: Check for the empty string? Am I missing something?

Comment: @TomFenech It's suble, but I believe OP is asking how to tell the difference between an existing attribute whose value is empty, and a non-existent attribute.

Comment: @TomFenech, editing uqestion (add PS), I copy the guide as a "**protest**": WHY (??) it not returns NULL for "not has attribute"?

Comment: @PeterKrauss:- Sorry if I am missing your context but what you are trying to achieve with `getAttribute` is better done using `hasAttribute`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [`DOMElement::hasAttribute`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.hasattribute.php)

```
if ($node->hasAttribute('class')) {do somthing};
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for [DOMElement::hasAttributeNS](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.hasattributens.php)

> DOMElement::hasAttributeNS — Checks to see if attribute exists

Like

```
if ($node->hasAttribute('class'))
{
//code
}
```